# Second-order partial derivative problem

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I need to find the second-order partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}$ of the following problem:

$$z(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x²+y²)$$

I got the first part:

First derivative is $$\frac{x}{x² + y²}$$

---

I then thought I would use the quotient rule to find the second derivative of x.

So this would mean: $$\frac{(x²+y²)-2x²}{(x²+y²)²}$$ right?
But the correct answer is: $\dfrac{y² - x²}{(x²+y²)²}$

Anyone care to explain why and what I did wrong?

Comment: You did everything right. :) The solution just computed $(x^2+y^2)-2x^2=x^2+y^2-2x^2=y^2-x^2$ in the nominator.

Comment: Ah! Ofcourse. I have been doing too much maths today I guess. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The correct derivative should be $[(x^2 + y^2) - 2x^2]/(x^2 + y^2)^2$ (i.e., the first $(x^2 + y^2)$ term should be in the denominator of the fraction, not its own term.)

Comment: Also, the standard English phrase would be "the second derivative with respect to $x$".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The edit misinterpreted OPs notation (which technically was wrong, but it was pretty clear from context...). I'll suggest an edit to fix that if not already done.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Piwi noted in a comment, your result is correct and you merely failed to simplify the numerator.